# scrolling issue while searching a text in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Is there any way to scroll the search text using iscroll? I am not able to go search element using iscroll + jQuery. I am searching a text but focus does not go to search text.

Comment: I am implementing here http://jsfiddle.net/naveennsit/JpvAy/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use scrollIntoView() like this

```
   $('.match.highlighted').get(0).scrollIntoView();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/JpvAy/5/)

Comment: What is the issue? @Rohit

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/naveennsit/JpvAy/8/

Please check my latest fiddle .Actually my issue is when I click fourth button from header and (top used 45 instend of 145 ).Then it above the text .how to remove that

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, btw there are no buttons in the latest fiddle

Comment: actually images are missing .click fourth image

Comment: So you want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/JpvAy/9/ 

css:  `#searchbar{
    margin-top:100px;
}`

Comment: Leave this i Don't want like that sorry..!! i have one more issue please help it is critical issue

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36003/discussion-between-rohit-and-anton)

Answer (score 0):

I already solved the code for you before

http://jsbin.com/umodoy/8

Comment: but here i am using Iscroll library